# Frequency table with common values of 5 tables

Tags: r

I have 5 data frames and I have to analize just the first column. From these, I must obtain a frequency table of their common words (not necessarily of all data frames, for example a word can appear just in two or more dataframes).

Then I must obtain a frequency table of common words of ALL dataframes

I just tried doing a for cycle but I seems very complicated. Moreover, dataframes have different dimentions. I didn't find any useful function.

Then I tried doing

```
lst1 <- list(a,b,c,d,e)  
newdat <- stack(setNames(lapply(lst1, "[", 1), seq_along(lst1)))[2:1]  
library(dplyr)  
newdat %>% group_by(val) %>% filter(uniqueN(ind) > 1) %>% count(val)
```

but it gives me an error

```
> stack(setNames(lapply(lst1, "[", 1), seq_along(lst1)))
Error in stack.default(setNames(lapply(lst1, "[", 1), seq_along(lst1))):
   at least one vector element is required
```

***Thank you***

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will find you receive more effective help if you provide more information, such as what you have tried so far. It is better to have a go at something and ask specific questions than to ask such open ended questions.

Comment: Get the datasets in a list and then do this `lst1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, ..., df5); newdat <- stack(setNames(lapply(lst1, "[", 1), seq_along(lst1)))[2:1]; library(dplyr);newdat %>% group_by(val) %>% filter(uniqueN(ind) > 1) %>% count(val)`

Comment: I just tried doing a for cycle but I seems very complicated. Moreover, dataframes have different dimentions. I didn't find any useful function

Comment: @akrun what do you mean with "val" and "ind"?

Comment: When you `stack` the `list`, it gives a two column data.frame with column names as 'val' and 'ind'

Comment: The column should be `values`.  Try here `df1 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE);df2 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[3:5], stringsAsFactors = FALSE);df3 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[4:7], stringsAsFactors = FALSE);lst1 <- list(df1, df2, df3);stack(setNames(lapply(lst1, `[[`, 1), seq_along(lst1)))[2:1] %>% group_by(values) %>% filter(uniqueN(ind) > 1) %>% count(values)`

Comment: @GiuliaSalvadori. Please check the data I created and the one you have.  I have the column as `character`.  Do you have a `factor` column that is extracted?  In that case,convert it to `character` class with `as.character` or else use `melt` from `reshape2` instead of `stack`

Comment: @akrun my columns are `character` of different lengths (54964,58621,70783,63367,60440)

Comment: It is alright.  You can check my example also, which is variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution using purrr & dplyr:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

lst1 <- list(mtcars=mtcars, iris=iris, chick=chickwts, cars=cars, airqual=airquality)  

lst1 %>%
  map_dfr(select, value=1, .id="df") %>%                # select first column of every dataframe and name it "value"
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(freq=n(),                                   # frequency over all dataframes
            n_df=n_distinct(df),                        # number of dataframes this value ocurrs
            dfs = paste(unique(df), collapse=",")) %>% 
  filter(n_df > 1) %>% 
  filter(n_df == 5)                                     # if value has to be in all 5 dataframes
```